# Subset dataframe based on Values in second dataframe

Tags: r

I have one dataframe, `df`, that has two columns as such:

```
> head(df1[,c(10,11)])
       ColA      ColB
1        12        20
2         7         5
3        32        38
4        37        46
5        15        15
6         4         4
```

I have a second dataframe, also with 2 columns with matching names. Instead, there are only two numbers, as such:

```
> head(df2)
       ColA      ColB
1        50        30
```

I want to subset values from `df1` based on the value in the corresponding column from `df2` . Doing this manually would look like this:

```
colA_vector <- df1[df1$colA < 50,]
colB_vector <- df1[df1$ColB < 30,]
```

How can I do so in a more general purpose way? I do not want to hardcode anything. The column name "ColA" or "ColB" could be anything (so solutions requiring those column names won't really work).

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of `50` use `df2$ColA`

Comment: I don't want to hardcode anything. ColA is subject to change with other analyses.

Comment: Please, can you [edit] your Q and show the expected result? I am asking because `colA_vector ` is not a vector but a dataframe. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base `R` we could do:

```
nms <- intersect(names(df1), names(df2))
df1[do.call(`&`, Map(`<`, df1[nms], df2[nms])),]
#   ColA ColB
# 1   12   20
# 2    7    5
# 5   15   15
# 6    4    4
```

Or just `df1[do.call('&', Map('<', df1, df2)),]` if both data.frames have the same order of columns and same names.

Using the package `fuzzyjoin` might be more readable however:

```
library(fuzzy_join)
fuzzy_semi_join(df1, df2, match_fun = `<`)
#   ColA ColB
# 1   12   20
# 2    7    5
# 5   15   15
# 6    4    4
```

**data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text="
ColA      ColB
1        12        20
2         7         5
3        32        38
4        37        46
5        15        15
6         4         4",h=T,strin=F)

df2 <- read.table(text="ColA      ColB
1        50        30",h=T,strin=F)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function if we want to do the same task repeatedly

```
f1 <- function(dat1, dat2, colName) {
        dat1[dat1[[colName]] < dat2[[colName]],]
  }

f1(df1, df2, "ColA")
#  ColA ColB
#1   12   20
#2    7    5
#3   32   38
#4   37   46
#5   15   15
#6    4    4

f1(df1, df2, "ColB")
#  ColA ColB
#1   12   20
#2    7    5
#5   15   15
#6    4    4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ColA = c(12L, 7L, 32L, 37L, 15L, 4L), ColB = c(20L, 
5L, 38L, 46L, 15L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

df2 <- structure(list(ColA = 50L, ColB = 30L), 
     class = "data.frame", row.names = "1")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`:

```
df1 %>%
  filter(df1[,1] < df2[,1])

  ColA ColB
1   12   20
2    7    5
3   32   38
4   37   46
5   15   15
6    4    4

df1 %>%
  filter(df1[,2] < df2[,2])

  ColA ColB
1   12   20
2    7    5
3   15   15
4    4    4
```

Subsetting based on both columns simultaneously:

```
df1 %>%
  filter(df1[,1] < df2[,1] & df1[,2] < df2[,2])

  ColA ColB
1   12   20
2    7    5
3   15   15
4    4    4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the `fuzzyjoin` join package or make your own function, you can just repeat the second dataframe.

```
df1 <- data.frame("ColA" = c(12, 7, 32),
             "ColB" = c(20, 5, 38))
df2 <- data.frame("ColA" = 50,
              "ColB" = 30)

n <- nrow(df1)
df2_new <- do.call("rbind", replicate(n, df2, simplify = FALSE))
df1_which <- as.data.frame(df1 < df2_new)

colA_vector <- df1[df1_which$ColA, "ColA"]
colB_vector <- df1[df1_which$ColB, "ColB"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a `tidyverse` funtion. Result is a list of the filtered data.frames.

```
foo <- function(x, y, ColA, ColB){
  require(tidyverse)
  var1 <- quo_name(ColA)
  var2 <- quo_name(ColB)
  x %>%
  select(a=!!var1, b=!!var2) %>% 
  mutate(colA_vector= a < y[[ColA]]) %>% 
  mutate(colB_vector= b < y[[ColB]]) %>% 
  gather(k, v, -a, -b) %>% 
  filter(v) %>%
  split(.$k) %>% 
  map(~select(.,-v,-k))
}
foo(df1, df2, "ColA", "ColB")
$colA_vector
   a  b
1 12 20
2  7  5
3 32 38
4 37 46
5 15 15
6  4  4

$colB_vector
    a  b
7  12 20
8   7  5
9  15 15
10  4  4
```